# Регулярные выражения с контролем символа по позиции

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas

Есть фрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'kks': ['00ARA98GH004', '00URA98GH005', '00ARA98GH006',    
                           00ARA98GH007',  '00URA98GH008', '00ARA98GH009',
                          '00URA98GH010', '00AUA98GH011',  '00ARA97GH001',
                          '00ARA97GH002', '00URA97GH003'], 
                  'sys_new': np.nan})
```

Нужен шаблон, который позволит обработать `df` таким образом, что бы значения из колонки 'kks' типа `ARA98` попали в результат, а значения, у которых первым символом является `U`, типа `URA98`, не попали в результат.
Мой шаблон: `r'[A-T, V-Z]{3}\d{2}'` данным условиям не удовлетворяет. Необходимо сопоставление только для 1-го символа. Записи типа `AUA98` и `AAU98` удовлетворяют условию.

Comment: Может, `r'^0*(?!URA)[A-Z]{3}\d{2}'`? Или проще, ``r'^0*(?!U)[A-Z]{3}\d{2}'``? ``r'^0*[A-TV-Z][A-Z]{2}\d{2}'``?  `USA99` валидно?

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем...
URA - это частный случай. Два символа после "U" могут быть любыми буквами, типа [A-Z]{2}.

Comment: Вот это самое оно: r'^0*[A-TV-Z][A-Z]{2}\d{2}', только первые две цифры откинем!
r'[A-TV-Z][A-Z]{2}\d{2}'
Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем их "откидывать"? Вы хотите сохранить совпадения в отдельном столбце или просто отфильтровать датафрейм?

Comment: `r'^0*([A-TV-Z][A-Z]{2}\d{2})'` не лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
r'^0*[A-TV-Z][A-Z]{2}\d{2}'
```

или

```
r'^0*(?!U)[A-Z]{3}\d{2}'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/pHS1Nb/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `0*` - ноль и более символов `0`
- `[A-TV-Z][A-Z]{2}` - одна заглавная латинская буква от `A` до `T` и от `V` до `Z` (все кроме `U`) и затем две любые заглавные латинские буквы
- `(?!U)` - следующий символ не должен быть `U`
- `[A-Z]{3}` - три заглавные латинские буквы
- `\d{2}` - две цифры

Comment: Спасибо!
Обе конструкции работают!
Отдельное спасибо за демо и Подробности!